# How do you change the application name in Grails 3?

Tags: grails, gradle

I'm a beginner using Gradle and Grails 3.x. In Grails 2.x `appName` could be changed in the `application.properties` file, now in Grails 3.0.8 the docs explain that it's possible in `application.yml` but I can't find a way to change `appName`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The application name is nearly irrelevant in Grails 3. It is used as the base name when you create a WAR file, but it's trivial to rename it before deploying, and you probably would regardless since it includes the application version.

It's used as the initial value of the `grails.codegen.defaultPackage` config setting, but you can change that easily:

```
grails:
   codegen:
      defaultPackage: 'com.foo.bar'
```

But I wouldn't bother with that since I don't use a default package - I specify the package for every artifact to avoid ending up with everything in one package.

In older versions of Grails it was used as the default context when running the app via `run-app`, e.g. `http://localhost:8080/appname` but in Grails 3 the default behavior of Spring Boot is used and there's no context by default. But if you want to specify the run-app context, you can do that (and optionally the port) with:

```
server:
   contextPath: /wheeeeeeee
   port: 9090
```

Gradle's default behavior is to use the directory name as its project name. If you want to override that, create a `settings.gradle` file and set the `rootProject.name` property:

```
rootProject.name = 'custom_app_name'
```

Comment: Good Job with grails 3,
Thanks Burt !

Comment: So I did find settings.gradle and application.yml for the base name and context path, but I have the reverse problem of having to rename the war file, which you say is trivial. But how?

Comment: mv oldname.war newname.war

Comment: I just tried it with `settings.gradle`, it absolutely does work.

Comment: Yeah, I was a dummyhead and put it in the wrong directory, deleting my misleading comment from before since it's plain wrong