# How can I modify the info.app.name in application.yml?

Tags: grails

I want to change my app name and I modified the `info.app.name` in **application.yml**, but it didn't work, it still use the project name. I need help.

The grails version is 3.1.4.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you change the application name in Grails 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32976039/how-do-you-change-the-application-name-in-grails-3)

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Why would You want to change app name in Grails 3? It doesn't do anything anyways. If you want to change it in the link, read Burt's answer in this post.
[How do you change the application name in Grails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32976039/how-do-you-change-the-application-name-in-grails-3)
Or just put this code in **application.yml**

```
server:
    port: 8080
    contextPath: '/veloroutersite'
```

Comment: Because you could very easily be using this programmatically in literally hundreds of places with ${grailsApplication.metadata.getApplicationName()} and you need the application name to match the contextPath

Comment: Also, the application name is displayed from the /info Spring Boot actuator endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to change your application's name you need to be sure that it will match the contextPath and that you tested the entire application after the change.

If you want to change the name given by the method `grailsApplication.metadata.getApplicationName()` you need to change the property `app.name` inside your `application.properties` file. The same file where your grails version is.

```
#Grails Metadata file
#Thu Apr 27 17:55:26 ART 2017
app.grails.version=3.1.4
app.name=YOUR_NEW_APPs_NAME
app.version=0.1
```

`grailsApplication.metadata.getApplicationName() // returns YOUR_NEW_APPs_NAME`