# Upgrading to Grails 3.2, now JSPs will not render

Tags: grails, upgrade

I am upgrading my application from Grails version 2.3.7 to version 3.2.2. My JSPs and other content like CSS and images all had to move from the old location of "web-app" to the new location of "src/main/resources/". Now, however, my JSPs will not load like they did before. For instance, my index page has always been http://hostname/app-name/homepage.jsp, and that always loaded just fine in Grails 2.x. Maybe there is just a configuration missing or something, does anyone have a suggestion. I have read the upgrade documentation, but have not found an answer to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

As Grails 3 uses Spring Boot there is no default context. So your application should be served under http://hostname:port.
You can change it back to the previous URL as suggested in [How do you change the application name in Grails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32976039/how-do-you-change-the-application-name-in-grails-3)

Comment: I read the linked article, here is my relevant setting in application.groovy:

    environments {
        development {
            // blah blah blah
            server {
                contextPath = "/app-name"
                port = 8080
            }
        }

and my UrlMappings:

    if ("DEVELOPMENT".equalsIgnoreCase(Environment.getCurrent().toString())) {
        "/" (view: "_homepage.jsp")
    } else {
        "/" (view: "homepage.jsp")
    }

Comment: but browsing to the application leads to this error:

Error 500: Internal Server Error
URI:/app-name/Class:javax.servlet.ServletExceptionMessage:Could not resolve view with name '_homepage.jsp' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'

    Line | Method
->> 1237 | render                in org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1037 | processDispatchResult in     ''
|    980 | doDispatch . . . . .  in     ''
|    897 | doService             in     ''
|    970 | processRequest . . .  in

Comment: The problem is that JSPs are not found, no matter where they reside (I have them in src/main/resources/public). When I step through the bowels of Grails code, it seems to always want to append ".gsp" to my pagename, and I get a 404.

Comment: @tkmilbaugh File an issue with a simple example project

Comment: @JamesKleeh how do I file an issue?